# The difference between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, date-arithmetic

I have been writing some queries about SQL Server in order to learn.

I wonder that how can I get the difference of today between 90 days ago in a SQL query?

Comment: lookup DATEDIFF(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: The difference between today and 90 days ago? I'm fairly certain that's a constant (ignoring DST changes, leap seconds, etc) :-)

Comment: yes I found DATEDIFF but I cannot do,
select datediff([....], ..., getdate())
but I dont know how to use
I only want to get the date from now to 3 months ago
that is to say today's date 18.08.2011 
and I want to find 18.05.2011

Comment: No, I think it's DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) because he said he wants 05/18 given 08/18. Still, that also returns current time, not midnight, which is typically required for range queries. See my answer. Also with SQL Server 2008 I recommend getting out of the habit of using implicit math against datetime because it doesn't work with the new types (date, datetime2, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DATEDIFF
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

```
DECLARE @90DaysAgo datetime
        ,@Today datetime

SET @90DaysAgo = DATEADD(d, -90, GETDATE())
SET @Today = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEDIFF(d, @90DaysAgo, @Today) --Returns 90
```

Answer (score 2):

You want [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), not DATEDIFF, and you need to decide whether you need 90 days ago:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-90,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

or 3 months ago:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,-3,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: thank you :), I get it.
Thank you Curt 
Thank you Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: good point - didn't mean to rush, just saw the OP's is fairly new and hasn't accepted answers yet, so I wanted to point that out as the polite and right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this to return the date and time for exactly 90 ago:

```
SELECT GETDATE()-90
```

output:

```
-----------------------
2011-05-20 10:55:12.360

(1 row(s) affected)
```

this will give you the date only for 90 days ago, with a time of 00:00:00.000:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),-90)
```

output:

```
-----------------------
2011-05-20 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will round correctly to midnight on the day 3 months ago (not 90 days ago) which seems to be what you want (08-18 -> 05-18 is 92 days since there were two 31sts in there).

```
...
WHERE column >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, 
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '20000101', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '20000101'));
```